# Plot-size control with RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr

I need to make a pdf-document with many plots with a lot of details. To keep the document file-size to under about 10MB, I try to plot with jpeg. But no matter how I try, the picture gets upscaled to full column width and therefore very pixelated.

What settings should I use instead of fig.width and fig.height?

Here is a modified version of the Tufte_handout included in RStudio. The third plot is the one I need better, but it should look like first plot (only smaller).

````
---
title: "Tufte Handout"
author: "John Smith"
date: "August 13th, 2014"
output: rmarkdown::tufte_handout
---

# Normal plot

```{r, fig.cap = "Sepal length vs. petal length, colored by species"}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
```

# Smaller plot

```{r, fig.cap = "Sepal length vs. petal length, colored by species", fig.width=2, fig.height=2}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
```

# Smaller jpeg plot

```{r, dev='jpeg', fig.cap = "Sepal length vs. petal length, colored by species", fig.width=2, fig.height=2}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
```
````

Comment: `out.width`, also, I wouldn't recommend jpeg. png might be better if you must use a raster format

Comment: What if you compressed after creation?